# I want to add one line text into my web page without crawling in search engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add one line text into my web page without crawling in search engine how can I add restriction on one line only. Anyone help me with that please,

I'm trying to get help from community,

I have my WordPress website on which I want to implement this functionality. Please guide me how can I do that?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `data-nosnippet` attribute to the corresponding HTML element.

From the Goolge docs:

> You can designate textual parts of an HTML page not to be used as a
> snippet. This can be done on an HTML-element level with the
> data-nosnippet HTML attribute on span, div, and section elements. The
> data-nosnippet is considered a boolean attribute. As with all boolean
> attributes, any value specified is ignored. To ensure
> machine-readability, the HTML section must be valid HTML and all
> appropriate tags must be closed accordingly.

Example:

`<p>This part is shown in a snippet. <span data-nosnippet>This part is not shown.</span></p>`

You can read more about it here:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag